# Hamiltonian flow is volume preserving

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

I was reading about the advantages of the Hamiltonian formalism over the Lagrangian one. One of the advantages is that "the Hamiltonian flow is volume preserving". Can anyone help me understand this? Why would volume preservation be an advantage?

Comment: See also [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28Hamiltonian%29).